# Store a variable from the array of object php

Tags: php, html, arrays

I have a php variabl `$purchase_data` which when I did

```
print_r('purchase_data');
```

I got the output as

```
Array
(
    [downloads] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 28
                    [options] => Array
                        (
                        )

                    [quantity] => 1
                )

        )

    [fees] => Array
        (
        )

    [subtotal] => 1
    [discount] => 0
    [tax] => 0
    [price] => 1
    [purchase_key] => a8d14e34ba425f9de6afe3ad4809587e
    [user_email] => esh@test.com
    [date] => 2014-05-11 20:07:22
    [user_info] => Array
        (
            [id] => 1
            [email] => eshtest.com
            [first_name] => esh
            [last_name] => 
            [discount] => none
            [address] => 
        )

    [post_data] => Array
        (
            [edd_email] => esh@test.com
            [edd_first] => esh
            [edd_last] => 
            [edd_phone] => 919995871693
            [edd-user-id] => 1
            [edd_action] => purchase
            [edd-gateway] => sample_gateway
        )

    [cart_details] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [name] => Shirt
                    [id] => 28
                    [item_number] => Array
                        (
                            [id] => 28
                            [options] => Array
                                (
                                )

                            [quantity] => 1
                        )

                    [item_price] => 1
                    [quantity] => 1
                    [discount] => 0
                    [subtotal] => 1
                    [tax] => 0
                    [price] => 1
                )

        )

    [gateway] => sample_gateway
    [card_info] => Array
        (
            [card_name] => 
            [card_number] => 
            [card_cvc] => 
            [card_exp_month] => 
            [card_exp_year] => 
            [card_address] => 
            [card_address_2] => 
            [card_city] => 
            [card_state] => 
            [card_country] => 
            [card_zip] => 
        )

)
```

How can i store the value to edd_phone  `[edd_phone]` into variable $mobileNo ?

Sorry for ths kind of a question.But badly need help

Comment: Use : 
`echo '<pre>'; print_r('purchase_data'); echo '</pre>';`
And update your answer with the formatted result, as the arrays are nested.

Comment: @abhishek Please check now..I did as u told

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to assign the value of [edd_phone] to $mobileNo , use this :

`$mobileNo = $purchase_data['post_data']['edd_phone'];`

As a side note : Your array is very complexly nested. If I were you, I would avoid such complex arrays.

Comment: Don't forget the `'` and always develop with error reporting on `E_ALL`.

Comment: @Rudie yes you are right, I totally forgot about the quotes for a moment.

Comment: @abhishek This is a wordpress plugins array which was pre built :P..I too wouldnt do this

Comment: @Piya I see, those plugins guys sure use complex algorithms.